# Only joining meta.stackoverflow.com gives you a Association Bonus?

Tags: support, reputation, linked-accounts, association

I've found many sites in the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#).

When I join to Meta Stack Overflow, the new account received +100 reputation on my account of both Stack Overflow (as "Association Bonus") and on Meta Stack Overflow.

But when I join other sites such as Electrical Engineering, Photography, etc.,
it only gives me +100 reputation on the new site, but doesn't give the bonus on Stack Overflow anymore.

I want to know why I only received an Association Bonus on Stack Overflow when I joined Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: You get association bonus only once per site.

Comment: One off-topic comment: please don't abuse the code formatting for general highlighting. It's incorrect and unnecessary.

Comment: @Bart , Thanks , I've edited :)

Comment: @zey My eyes thank you. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Association bonus is a one-time thing per site. Once you reach 200 reputation on any site, you get +100 on all sites that you participate on. If you join any sites after this, the +100 is awarded belatedly.